# How do I send files in PHP via CURL? @filename won't work

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send an image via POST using PHP's CURL methods.
I am sending the image to an API that expects the POST field 'photo_file' to be an image.
I set the 'photo_file' to @ followed by the file name.
However, when I make the request the API receives the literal string '@filename' instead of the file contents.

Here is the relevant code:

**Calling code:**

```
$data = array(
  'campaign_id' => $_POST['campaign_id'],
);
$img_source = realpath($img_source); // "/Users/andrew/Sites/roo/9699d27bb09fda3133701ca9af084e3d.jpg"
$response = $y->upload_photo($img_source, $data);
```

**$y->upload_photo()**:

```
public function upload_photo($img_source, $data) {
    $fields = array(
        'campaign_id' => $data['campaign_id'],
        'photo_file' => '@' . $img_source
    );

    return $this->request('photos', $fields, 'post');
}
```

**$this->request()** (relevant parts):

```
public function request($function, $fields = array(), $method = 'get') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $this->host . $function;

    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL                         => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => array('Accept: application/json', 'Expect:'),
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE                 => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => 1,
    );
    if ($method == 'post') {
        $curlConfig[CURLOPT_POST]               = 1;
        $curlConfig[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = true;
        $curlConfig[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $fields;
    }

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    list($header_blob, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 3);

    $this->http_status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($body);
}
```

The API is returning an error, and when its dev looked at the logs he saw that the request on his end was:

```
'campaign_id' => '4'
'photo_file' => '@/Users/andrew/Sites/roo/9699d27bb09fda3133701ca9af084e3d.jpg'
```

so adding @ to the beginning of the file didn't actually send the contents of the file, like I understand it's supposed to. Also, the API works fine with other platforms that use it, so the problem is definitely on my end.

Comment: [PHP 5.6 changes the `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to `true`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), are you running 5.6?

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken, that setting `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to `false` fixed the problem (and also gave me the warning: `Deprecated: curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead`)